# Count values greater than 0 in SpatialPolygonsDataframe R

Tags: r

I have a SpatialPolygonsDataframe with > 100 layers and I would like to get a single layer showing the total count of where the values of all the layers are greater than 0. I have tried converting to a rasterstack but still cannot find a method that will summarise all the layers by count. Any suggestions?

Comment: A reproducible example would certainly increase your chance of success.

Comment: Do you mean the SPDF has >100 layers? Or >100 features? Or >100 data fields?

Comment: Quite. There's no room for more than one "layer" in a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame in my sp-dictionary. I think you mean nrow(spolydf) > 100. Yeah?  Please clarify the rest I cannot make sense of it.

Comment: OK some clarification needed - I'm still thinking in a GIS mindset - > 100 data fields (kernel density ranges for different animals calculated with kernelUD).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For illustration sake, let's take a look at what rowSums, a special instance of apply, is actually doing. Understanding apply functions in R opens a door that allows you to run more complex analysis, optimize code and speed up processing.

The reason that I expand on @cengal answer is because if one wants to write more complex functions that operate on rows or columns then the apply function comes into play.

Create example data used in @cengal's example

```
dat <- data.frame(var1 = c(sample(c(0:9), 10, replace = T)), 
  var2 = c(sample(c(0:9), 10, replace = T)), 
  var3 = c(sample(c(0:9), 10, replace = T)))
```

Here apply is used to produce the "NonZeroFields" vector.

```
apply(dat, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) {length( x[x > 0] )} )
```

Now, what if we wanted an index of the row(s) in each column containing zero's? We can use apply, changing the margin to columns, to create a list object where each list element corresponds to row(s) containing zero(s) in each column.

```
dat[,3][4] <- 0 #add extra zero so one resulting vector is > 1
( row0 <- apply(dat, MARGIN=2, FUN=function(x) { which(x == 0) }) )
  unique(unlist(row0))
```

We can then use the index values in row0 to remove rows containing zero values. Note; this will work on sp class objects as well. You will need to access the @data slot when using apply, but not when removing polygons with an index (the below syntax will work on data.frame or sp objects without specifying the @data slot).

```
( dat <- dat[-unique(unlist(row0)),] )
```

Answer (score 0):

A spatial data frame works like a data frame. So if I understand your question correctly, you can just use `rowSums`.

```
set.seed(107) 

mydf <- data.frame(var1 = c(sample(c(0:9), 10, replace = T)), 
  var2 = c(sample(c(0:9), 10, replace = T)), 
  var3 = c(sample(c(0:9), 10, replace = T))

mydf$NonZeroFields <- rowSums(mydf > 0)

mydf

   var1 var2 var3 NonZeroFields
1     5    1    2             3
2     0    0    4             1
3     5    1    4             3
4     0    5    2             2
5     1    3    5             3
6     5    7    5             3
7     3    7    7             3
8     6    7    8             3
9     2    9    7             3
10    0    3    6             2
```

Comment: There is a base function called "df". Naming objects the same as existing functions is bad coding convention, that can cause code to fail inexplicably.

Comment: @Jeffrey Evans: Absolutely correct. Thanks for pointing this out. I renamed the variable.